# How is the unit of kinetic energy equivalent to $\mathrm{Pa}\cdot\mathrm{m}^3$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, units, unit-conversion

I know that the unit of kinetic energy is Joules, J. However, the book I have says that the "unit of kinetic energy is equivalent to $\text{Pa}\cdot\text{m}^3$. I have been trying to prove this result, which is also shown on wikipedia, but came to no result.

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know unit of kinetic energy is Joule 
where
 $$\rm Joule=N\cdot m$$

But from pressure equation $P=F/A$
$$\rm 1N=Pa m^2$$

Putting this into $J= N\cdot m$
$$\begin{align}J &=Pa ~\mathrm{m^2\times m}\\J &=Pa ~\mathrm{m^3}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

A pressure is no than more a force applied on a surface, so $[P] = [{\rm Force}]\times L^{-2}$. However, work is an energy, so $[E] = [{\rm Force}]\times L$. So we have $[E] = [P]\times L^3$. Since kinetic energy is an energy, $[K] = [P]\times L^3$, in other words, the unit of kinetic energy is equivalent to $Pa\cdot m^3$.